# Populate Tables in Pl/SQL using declared sequences

Tags: loops, plsql, sequences

I need to populate lot of newly created tables with minimum 30 rows in my database using sequences. Please post the syntax.

Shall I use loop?

Any suggestions and solutions welcome.

Your help is much appreciated in resolving this issue.

I've created three sequences and added values to 3 columns with 30 rows. For `id`, `tel_no` and `emp_id` is it ok to create 3 sequences and add 30 rows. What if one column is varchar2 like `name`. At the moment 3 sequences are populating values in 3 columns but adding null in 'name column'. Please help on how to add 30 names and resolve this. I am very sorry I am new to this, please do not hesitate to clarify. many thanks for your time.

To summarize: I just want sequence to generate sequence for numbers for all the rows and prompt me for the names.

Comment: You wrote a lot but didn't tell us much.  What do your tables look like?  How many columns do you need populating?  The same sequence for all tables or will each table have its own sequence?  Does "minimum 30 rows" mean you want to parameterise this?  How will you pass the table names to the code?  People here are only too willing to help but you need to give us sufficient information.  Help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit at what you want, but how about:

```
create table test
(id number);

create sequence seq_test
start with 1
maxvalue 999999999999999999999999999
minvalue 1
nocycle
nocache
noorder;

insert into test(id)
select seq_test.nextval from dual
connect by level <= 30;

commit;
```

Comment: many thanks for your response. I do apologise for not explaining it properly.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I do apologise for not explaining it properly.1) I've created normal blank 20 tables with varchar2, number, integer.(like department, religion, address etc) 2) yes I only need to add 30 rows per table.3) all the tables have 10 columns. I hope this helps. @tbone

Comment: Thanks, it is working. Also, is it possible to add data to multiple columns in a table by single sequence statement like test(id, tel_no, emp_id). the query above is only for test(id).

Comment: @peterB many things are possible, not quite sure what u want tho.  If using 1 seq for many cols, do u want same number used for each col in a given row, or diff nums (row1: 1,1,1 row2: 2,2,2... or row1: 1,2,3 row 2: 4,5,6...)

Comment: many thanks. That's resolved, I've created three sequences and added values to 3 columns with 30 rows. one last thing (for id, tel_no and emp_id its ok to create 3 sequences and add 30 rows. what if one column is varchar2 like 'name'. at the moment 3 sequences are populating values in 3 columns but adding null in 'name column'. pls help on how to add 30 names and resolve this. I am very sorry I am new to this, please do not hesitate to clarify.many thanks for your time.

Comment: @peterB a sequence generates a sequence of numbers.  I dont understand, u want to also generate random names (varchar2)?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned where you're going to run the scripts - if it's in SQL*Plus then you can make use of substitution variables

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..COUNT LOOP
        INSERT INTO emp
                    (id,
                     tel_no,
                     emp_id,
                     NAME)
        VALUES      (id_seq.next_val,
                     tel_no_seq.nextval,
                     emp_id_seq.nextval,
                     &name);
    END LOOP;
END;
```